# Footer not spaning 100% width of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My footer seems to be getting stuck inside of the margins. but as you can see the div .mid-content is spanning 100% of the page. I can not figure This out it has me dumb founded. I have the footer with bootstrap columns for the text.
Thank you for your help
ps. Please excuse any mistakes I make with in the community rules I am very new to this community.

Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/6IACrTJVfr)

Comment: CSS in demo is botched.

Comment: Yea is it possible for you to read over the code and help me out.

Comment: It looks ok: http://www.bootply.com/OHysHbdZrI, I added background-color to footer, it's spanning full width.  Also, in terms of mistakes regarding community rules - you should explain your issue, include code, and explain what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get where your problem is? the footer and content are 100% wide.

Comment: I don't have a clue what you are talking about, but I'm going to presume you want to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar. Just previewing your mockup in a new window (click the screen icon on the right) gets rid of it.

Comment: On my side its not spanning the full width

Answer (score 0):

I had success by revising the two CSS definitions, below.

The `.wrapper-footer` should be full width and the `.footer` limited by `max-width`.

The `background-color` should be on `.wrapper-footer` rather than `.footer`.

### ORIGINAL CSS:

```css
.wrapper-footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1370px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:100%;    
}
```

### REVISED CSS:

```css
.wrapper-footer {
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

.footer {
    margin:50px auto 0;
    max-width:1370px;   
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/9r57PxTT8K)

Comment: Would you like me to post the full css document?

Comment: That might be helpful. It's best if you can include relevant code in your question itself, so people can readily see it.

Comment: Are you still testing the "GET A FREE RENTAL APPRAISEL" page? I pasted your CSS directly into my bootply and it seems to work as expected: http://www.bootply.com/dPc05cXION.

Answer (score 0):

Well do not worry i have found the issue. There was a div that was not  closed properly above it.